# how to eliminate the unused lines from output

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, playonlinux

I am new to scripting I got below output from my script.

OUTPUT:

```
/opt/soft/was85qa/WebSphere/gct8apps_qa_node/config/cells/gct8apps_qa_cell/clusters/elmd_qa/variables.xml
```

How to eliminate below lines

```
/opt/soft/
/WebSphere/gct8apps_qa_node/config/cells/gct8apps_qa_cell/clusters/
/variables.xml
```

final output should be like below

```
was85qa & elmd_qa
```

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do, and where this paths (?) are coming from ? With the information given, we can provide you with MANY useless non-generic options. Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Is it always the same that you have to eliminate? Does it depende on the depth of the folders? The name?...

Comment: its always the same I need to eliminate

Comment: @RoVo I am extracting the output from one of my file

Answer (score 1):

If the text is always the same, you can just use `sed` search and replace function and hard-code what needs to be excluded:

```
echo $OUTPUT | sed -r 's#/opt/soft/([^\/]*)/WebSphere/gct8apps_qa_node/config/cells/gct8apps_qa_cell/clusters/([^\/]*)/variables.xml#\1 \& \2#'
```

You could also use `cut`, because if it's always the same, the strings you're looking for are always on the same position (--> 4 and 11).

```
echo $OUTPUT | cut -d'/' -f 4,11 --output-delimiter=" & "
```

Instead of `echo $OUTPUT` you can add the part beginning with the pipe (`|`) directly behind your command to run the script.